# Astronomer watching planets in a solar system

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, contest-math

> There is exactly one astronomer on every planet of a certain system. He watches the closest planet. The number of the planets is odd and all of the distances are different. Prove that there one planet being not watched. *(Source: All Soviet Union Math Olympiad 1966)*

Here is my solution:

> Suppose for convenience that when a planet watches another planet, the astronomer on the planet is the one watching. Consider the smallest distance between two planets; call them $A$ and $B$. The pair $A$ and $B$ will watch each other, since there is no other planet closer to either of them.
>
> **Case 1:** If the next smallest distance is between $A$ or $B$ and another planet, that other planet will watch $A$ or $B$ (suppose it is $B$), so that $B$ has two planets watching it. In order for all the planets to be watched, each planet must watch a different planet, as there are $n$ planets to be watched by $n$ watchers. But since there are two planets watching $B$ at the same time, at least one planet will be left unwatched in this case.
>
> **Case 2:** If the next smallest distance is between two other planets $C$ and $D$, they will watch each other. If there is a planet that watches either $C$ or $D$, we apply Case 1 again with $C$ or $D$. If the next smallest planet is between two other planets $E$ and $F$, we apply Case 2 again but with $E$ and $F$.
>
> If all planets are watched, we would proceed through this algorithm without Case 1 happening, in other words, all planets watch each other in pairs. But there are an odd number of planets, resulting in it being impossible for all planets to watch each other in pairs. So we conclude that there must be at least one planet left unwatched, and we are done.

I was wondering if this proof is rigorous enough, and if there are any other solutions that work?

Comment: I think the proof would be easier to follow if you used induction.  As you have said, we may assume that no two astronomers watch the same planet.  Then when A and B watch each other, no one else watches A or B, and we immediately reduce to the $n-2$ case.

Comment: While I agree with **saulspatz** that the argument could be more neatly cast as an induction, what you’ve done is correct and reasonably clear.